# ASP.NET - Concatenate String Memory Leak

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am supporting an application, which uses lots of String concatenations and I believe this is the cause of a memory leak which eventually causes an OutOfMemory exception.  Please have a look at the code below:

```
Public Sub ConcatenateString() As String Dim Test1 As String

Test1 = "Hello" 
Test1=Test1 & "my" 
Test1=Test1 & "name" 
Test1=Test1 & "is" 
Test1=Test1 & "joe" 
Test1=Test1 & "blogs" 
Test1=Test1 & "what" 
Test1=Test1 & "is" 
Test1=Test1 & "yours?" 'line 10

return Test1

End Sub
```

I believe there are nine Strings in memory at line ten as String is an immutable object, but only one reference to the String Test1 that contains: "Hello my name is Joe Blogs what is yours?".  My question is; are all of these Strings picked up by the garbage collector when they go out of scope? i.e. when the sub routine finishes running.  I seem to have a memory leak and am thinking that I should really be using a StringBuilder object.

Comment: A few strings can't be enough to cause a memory exception except on a system with no swap or RAM left, or a system with approximately 1MB of RAM.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh ,The system that I am supporting concatenates very large Strings.  This was a very simple example.

Comment: @w0051977, in such case as you have stated ... you need to use `stringbuilder class` and don't go for concatenating.

Answer (score 3):

in such case as you have stated ... you need to use [stringbuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and don't go for concatenating.

Garbage collection doesn't necessarily happens just after the method block is over but at some later time.

See this links for a better comparison and explanation between `String concatenation` and `StringBuilder`.

[Improving String Handling Performance in .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302329.aspx)

[String Concatenation vs Memory Allocation](http://www.cumps.be/nl/blog/commented/string-concatenation-vs-memory-allocation)

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that the concatenation of strings, even if they are very large, would cause an out of memory exception.  In these days of virtual memory, out of memory exceptions rarely are an indication of actually running out of RAM.  Rather, the usual suspect for an out of memory exception is if you run out of system handles (e.g. GDI objects, File handles).  You can see the total number of handles being used by showing those columns in your task manager.  The maximum handles each process can create depends on which version of windows you have, and how it's setup, but typically, the maximum is 10,000.

Once the strings that are created are no longer referenced, they are considered dead and the garbage collector will destroy them and free the memory.  So, yes, as soon as it exist the method, all those strings will be eventually collected, but there's no guarantee when it will get around to doing so.  If you really need to force the garbage collector to collect the dead objects immediately, you can do so by calling `GC.Collect()`.

However, concatenating strings like that is bad practice.  It is very inefficient, especially with large strings.  You should be using the StringBuilder in such cases:

```
Public Sub ConcatenateString() As String Dim Test1 As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    builder.Append("Hello")
    builder.Append("my")
    builder.Append("name") 
    builder.Append("is")
    builder.Append("joe") 
    builder.Append("blogs") 
    builder.Append("what")
    builder.Append("is")
    builder.Append("yours?")
    Return builder.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the suggestion about file handles.  Is there a useful free tool you can suggest for finding memory leaks.  I am using windbg at the moment, but the learning curve seems to be steep.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with any.  With tracking handles, as I said, you can see the current count of handles go up in the task manager as you step through the code, so it's pretty easy to determine where those leaks are coming from (if they exist) without third-party tools.